# Integration of Azure Service Bus messages between C# and PHP

Tags: azure, integration, servicebus

Going over [development notes from Microsoft for PHP Azure bus](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/php/how-to-guides/service-bus-topics/#SendMessage), I see PHP bus library has `$message->getBody()`, where as C# library has `message.GetBody<T>();` and expects a type.

How would we send messages (as simple classes) between PHP/C# in a flexible way that doesn't break should a newer message version be received?

Comment: what did you try and what didn't work? Your question doesn't show any attempt to solve it on your own? And going to the root of your question `doesn't break should a newer message version be received` I would say `avoid using generic methods, but rather do the serialization/deserialization on your own`.

Comment: @astaykov thanks for the reply, boilerplate code for the bus is the easy part and yes we can send messages OK - my question is what should these messages be? I have thought about JSON, but really need some direction as the little knowledge I have for Azure PHP to C# is probably dangerous! Moreover, the C# method seems to only accept a generic type for GetBody<T>()

Comment: Speaking of which... you are right. There is only Generic GetBody, but there also is overload [GetBody<T>(XmlObjectSerializer serializer)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh125098.aspx), which you could use to inject your own XmlObjectSerializer instance. And your `T` in that case could be a very simple .NET object with single Text Property, which is the JSON payload. I think this is best way to handle multiple message formats without changing queue logic.

Comment: does this problem exist for Azure Java Service Bus SDK as well?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the default data type for php based brokered messages is string.  Depending on what you are sending here are a few options:

1. Send data using the key value pairs collection on the BrokeredMessage. php: `$message->setProperty("Key", "Value");` OR c#: `brokeredMessage.Properties.Add("Key","Value");`
2. Serialize all of your objects to json then insert into the BrokeredMessage body. If retrieving in C# use `BrokeredMessage.GetBody<string>()`

Another tip is that in C# you can only call BrokeredMessage.GetBody() once.